# Глобальная область видимости для модулей Webpack, JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

У меня есть модули которые мне нужно подключать во многих файлах, я могу сделать это в каждом файле по отдельности подключая их через export import но могу ли я подключить их в глобальную область один раз?

Как бы я хотел это видеть

utils.js

```
var a = 10
function b(){
   console.log(a)
}
export {a, b}`
```

index.js

```
import * as utils from './utils'
```

ЛюбойДругойФайл.js

```
console.log(a) // 10
b() // 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сделать доступ во всех файлах, нужно добавить в window.b = fun();
Можно вызывать просто b()